# Reactstrap Bootstrap Navbar not working in react app

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, navbar, create-react-app, reactstrap

I created a react app with 'create react-app'.

I am trying now to add a navbar from Reactstrap. I do copy-paste from  Reactstrap (I am adding this as one react component) [website](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }
  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">GitHub</NavLink>
              </NavItem>
              <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                  Options
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Option 1
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Option 2
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Reset
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and it does not work. I am getting this in my react app:

[image: navbar in react app]

I had similar problems with Bootstrap, React and Navbar before but I am really surprised it is happening in Reactstrap.
Do you know why is it so?

Comment: you need to import the css `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` as stated in the docs https://reactstrap.github.io/

Comment: Thanks! This works. I added bootstrap too. I was not aware I should do it additionally while using Reactstrap.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need also bootstrap, and react-dom:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save reactstrap react react-dom
```

---

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
```

Answer (score 6):

You should make sure you have

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

imported into the `index.js` file created automatically when you create react app.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.

```
import { NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import { NavLink as ReactLink } from 'react-router-dom';

<NavLink tag={ReactLink} to="/home" activeClassName="active" >Home</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's not documented, you have to use  as follows with react-router:

`<NavLink tag={Link} to="/somewhere">`

IE:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { NavLink } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  return (
    <NavLink tag={Link} to="/somewhere">
      {props.item.name}
    </NavLink>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

just install

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install jquery
```

then import them in index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle'
```

it worked for me while i am fail to toggle.

for more fetures you can install popper as well